# Как в bitrix получить коэффициент единицы измерения по id товара?

Tags: php, битрикс

Как в bitrix получить коэффициент единицы измерения товара по id?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделать это можно через D7. В нем есть класс `MeasureRatioTable` и метод `getCurrentRatio()`.

```
$measureData = \Bitrix\Catalog\MeasureRatioTable::getCurrentRatio($productID);
```

На вход метод принимает либо массив идентификаторов товара либо числовой идентификатор товара.

На выходе вы получаете массив коэффициентов единиц измерения для переданных товаров.